# Is it possible to integrate Cocos2d iphone into an existing program that i'm coding?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i actually need a simple enlarging animation (a small card enlarging into a larger card, drag and drop into a bucket) at any point in time, there is only 1 animation.

If Cocos2d integration is possible, i would actually want to add in more animations into my project.

my project is currently a Nav-Tab Project.

So i have my own custom classes in the project.

Just wondering whether will Cocos2d be able to be added into my current project without any glitch or whatsoever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add cocos2d to any UIView. So yes, it will integrate fine with app you are building.

Answer (score 0):

My [Learn Cocos2D book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) (2nd Edition) has a new chapter about mixing Cocos2D and UIKit views. One part of the chapter specifically explains step by step how to add Cocos2D to an existing UIKit app (regular iPhone app without Cocos2D).

You'll learn how to add the Cocos2D files, how to create a Cocos2D GL View in your nib, how to setup and start Cocos2D respectively stop (suspend) Cocos2D if you need the full performance for other things (ie a scrolling table view).

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/